# Basic samba server install?

Tags: linux, samba, file-server

I am looking to do a simple Samba server install on my Ubuntu 11.04 VM.

What I need is some shares to be public and few shares to be private.

What I need to know is what I have to keep in the config file in order to maintain a basic configuration. I want to lose the parts about domain controllers and profiles.

Oh yeah and I want to keep the printer sharing ability.

Do I just delete the part I don't want to keep? or is there a science to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [system-config-samba](http://ubuntuguide.net/createmodifydelete-samba-shares-with-system-config-sambagui-in-ubuntu-linux)? This is an UI to configure Samba easily. It may not be as powerful as vim but for a simple configuration should suffice.

Comment: I am running command line, can't do GUI

Comment: @Solignis Option B would be to get the basic setup on a machine with a GUI, copy the samba.conf file over to the server, and do any last minute tweaking there. That should get you up and running

Comment: That is a good idea, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything, make a back of Samba's configuration file so you have something to go back to if need be.

If swat is installed, take a look at that.  It's Samba's web based configuration tool.  It's a bit ugly but should get you going.

If you truly only have command line access, I suggest you do some reading before you start playing with settings.  [Samba-3 by Example](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-Guide/) will get you up and running fairly quickly.

And remember, [testparm](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/testparm.1.html) is your friend.

Comment: Yep, I made a backup of the original smb.conf. I don't think swat is installed. What does testparm do exactly? I ran it and it gave me a dump of smb.conf that consisted of only the values that were uncommented. Is that some kind of template in a way?